# Display all tags even if they are not assigned to a post

Tags: posts, pages, tags

Tags will not display if they are not assigned to a post/page. Is there a function that will allow a tag to be displayed when it is not assigned to a post or page?

example: If you click on the "`electric wall oven`" link on this page
http://www.shockwave.net.au/perth-electrician-work/electric-wall-oven/ it returns a "Nothing Found" because the tag isn't assigned to a post.

Comment: Displayed where? In the tag cloud widget?

Comment: yes and no... displayed as they would normally if you clicked on their link in a post.

Comment: In effect, it's similar to being able to show an empty category.

Comment: I tried this... but it didn't work...
`add_filter('get_terms_args','showemptytags');

function showemptytags($args) {
$args['hide_empty']=false;
return $args;
}`

Comment: I don't understand what you expect to display. The link in your updated question _is_ displaying the tag. Your template just displays "Nothing Found" if no posts are found. So you need to change the template.

Comment: That's what I'm asking... if the tag has no posts then i want it to be displayed as if it did have a post. I'd rather not edit the template.

Comment: Well you have to. It's a template issue. Use a child theme if it's not your own theme.

Comment: So there's no way to create a function that will 'trick' WP into thinking all tags are assigned to a post?

Comment: No. There is no filter to change whether or not a query appears to have posts. The issue is solely the logic of the template. Templates will have code like `if ( have_posts() ) :` and `else:`. Themes can display the name and description of a category/tag whether or not `have_posts()` is true. Your theme displays the title and description only if `have_posts()` is true. This is a template-level decision, not anything to do with the functionality of WordPress.